# font-face not showing some characters correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-face

I have imported a font in my code like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BYekan';
    src: url('/Contents/Fonts/BYekan.eot');
    src: url('/Contents/Fonts/BYekan.woff') format('woff'),url('/Contents/Fonts/BYekan.ttf') format('truetype'),url('/Contents/Fonts/BYekan.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

When I run my code in Chrome, sometimes some characters are shown like squares.

[image]

As soon as I resize the window, the characters go normal and they're displayed correctly!

I have `<meta charset="utf-8">` in my code so the problem is somewhere else.

Any ideas? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Can you give me a link to font-face?

Comment: You wanna check the font files? here:  http://s6.picofile.com/file/8205208576/Fonts.zip.html

Comment: As I understood it's an Arabic font, and I should check it on Arabian language?

Comment: Is [it](https://jsfiddle.net/tenckfgd) work, for you?

Comment: It's Persian actually. The link u provided has a non-smooth BYekan font. I've searched a lot to find the smooth one I gave you. But I don't know why this problem rises up. This issue just happens with Chrome and it doesn't happen all the time.

Comment: Also yours fonts work for me. Look for example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y55sd25t), you need change paths to yours and also I have meta tag with utf-8 charset. [Without](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s127/sh/e5293971-0ba5-4a98-b0e8-dd2787e6a7b0/9a49f230d1e2a5441ebc5a44169bc201) font, and [with](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s127/sh/108ac2f6-77a7-4fa1-bd79-4b9aa7740362/7295e69c3b58fa3e5ed9e70440cd6c9a) font.

Comment: Is my comment was helpful?

Comment: No, Problem still exists. I think it's an issue with Chrome. Because it just happens in Chrome and when I resize the window the characters are shown correctly! It's kinda weird :|

Comment: @AleshaOleg Found the solution! Check my answer above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

If we don't set `font-size` for out texts, the default font size is `1em`. And apparently Chrome has problems with this font size for some fonts!

So I just set `font-size` something else (for example `font-size: 1.001em`) and now the fonts are displayed correctly :)

Answer (score -2):

Try and check another font. 
May be the errors in your font file.

Comment: This is a troubleshooting  step not an answer

Comment: I know. But I can not add comments to the question, I have not enough reputation.

Comment: @Olga try to earn reputation:)

Comment: @Olga Chrome causes problem. Not my fonts. I found the solution. Check my answer above.